# Bad Request: sticker set name invalid

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Trying to call [createNewStickerSet](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#createnewstickerset), but getting an error

```
error_code=400, description='Bad Request: sticker set name invalid'
```

params:

```
user_id = 1111,
name = "what_den_things",
title = "What Denis thinks",
png_sticker = "BQADAgADxQIAAsQQMUqjvj3PCWFVMwI", // I tried url, file,  file_id here, seems it has nothing to do with the problem
emoji: = ""
```

I tried also uploadStickerFile method, works like a charm.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there was a glitch in documentation, as by https://github.com/tdlib/td/issues/466#issuecomment-456361390
name of the sticker set must end with `by_YourBotName`